# Email works with route using get request but email will not send with post request and there are no errors just a page refresh

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I have verified emails are sending via mailgun with a public function mail using a get request with no data on the page. Trying to send an email from a contact page with a POST request simply refreshes the page with no errors but email does not send.

I have set the .env and config.mail / config.services and successfully send mail using a get request in web.php.

First I used Terminal php artisan make:mail. Then I created two routes for a contact page (GET / POST), created a contact view (works), send the data to PagesController.php, run a validation of the three inputs, pass the data to Mail::send. On click of submit button the page refreshes with no errors (validation not working) and email doesn't send.

PagesController.php:

Namespace(

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use App\Mail\Welcome;
use Mail;
```

class PagesController extends Controller
{

```
public function getContact(){
   return view('pages/contact');
    }

public function postContact(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request,[
     'email' => 'required|email',
     'subject' => 'min:3',
     'message' => 'min: 3'
  ]);

$data = array(
    'email' => $request->email,
    'subject' => $request->subject,
    'bodyMessage' => $request->message
  );

\Mail::send('email.Test', $data, function($message) use ($data){
    $message->from($data['email']);
    $message->to('visionquest.jesse@gmail.com');
    $message->subject($data['subject']);
 });
```

}

Web.php:

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');
Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');
```

Test.blade.php:

```
<html>

 <h1> Email from: {{ $email }}</h1>

 <p> {{ $subject }} </p>
 <br><br>
 <hr>
 <p>{{ $bodyMessage}}</p>
```

contact.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| Contact')

@section('content')


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
      <hr>
      <form acion="{{ url('contact') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="email">Email:</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="subject">Subject:</label>
          <input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label name="message">Message:</label>
          <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-             control">Type your message here...</textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Send message" class="btn btn-success">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

@endsection

All I want to do is pull the information from the form and send it via email to a set address. I have been working on this for over week and now that I am not getting errors I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this above  the form in your blade file. You would be able to see the validation errors if any :

```
@if ($errors->any())
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <div>{{$error}}</div>
     @endforeach
 @endif
```

Also change :

```
<form acion="{{ url('contact') }}">
```

To

```
<form action="{{ url('contact') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: I tried that. Its not generating any errors. I can see in the URL that that string data is there but its not doing anything

Comment: ran php artisan cache:clear and tried again with same result. Also the mailgun logs are not showing any sent email requests

Comment: If you do dd(1); above mail::send in controller, does it reach to the dump or it redirects back?

Comment: Im not sure how to tell if it reaches to the dump. I added the code and its not changing the behavior. Just refreshes the page over and over

Comment: here is what my URL shows on submit: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact?_token=50yo0wo2N8jkFMtOJGqaGBMaHW75Xl2fCUvKd9Iw&email=jesse%40vqventure.com&subject=New+Testing+of+Email+from+Laravel&message=another+test

Comment: Is your form `action=""` is a correct url? I can guess its not :)

Comment: form action="{{ url ('contact') }}" and Route::post('contact', PagesController@postContact')

Comment: If you do dd(1) in controller's postContact before validation, what does it show? Aso try remove space in `min: 3` to `min:3` and try?

Comment: I noticed my form was missing method="POST". I added this to it but still its the same result

Comment: The spelling of action is incorrect. You have `acion` where as it should be `action`

Comment: adding the dd(1) above validation refreshes page with a black bar in the header with 1 on it.

Comment: Wow..... stupid spelling. Thank your for the help Mihir! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

put some method on your form  : **method="POST"** because once you will submit it, it will route to the **GET** route not the **POST** route since you did not declare a method on your form